# Script (or my logic in code) is causing deadlocks

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, deadlock

Below you will see the stored procedure that causes locks in Oracle 11.  I am unfortunately in a corporate environment that doesn't allow me access to trace logs, or basically anything.  So I've read tons of recommendations for how to do that, and cry that I can't do it.  I'm not sure you can even determine from below if this would be the culprit.  Anyway, thanks for everyone's time.

```
MERGE INTO my_owner.my_table tgtT
  USING (SELECT diTT, sisCd FROM my_owner.NGR_DMNSN_TYP
    where DMNSN_NM_TXT = 'myname'
    and sisCd = 'RefDB') srcT
  ON ( TGTT.diTT = srcT.diTT and TGTT.ID_TXT = 50000 )
  WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET TGTT.DSCRPTN_TXT = 'dfdf', TGTT.NM_TXT = 'bldfdfah'
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN 
    INSERT (TGTT.DSCRPTN_TXT, TGTT.NM_TXT, TGTT.diTT, TGTT.ID_NBR, TGTT.ID_TXT)
      VALUES ('ee', 'ee', srcT.diTT, 50000, '50000' );
```

Comment: Deadlock or just blocking? Does it deadlock when a single session calls this procedure, or when it's being called from more than one session simultaneously, and is it reproducible? If your DBAs won't supply the information you need to investigate, then they will have to do the investigation themselves...

Comment: i'm not sure how a merge statement can cause a deadlock on it's own but one thing you can do immediately is to split the merge into `insert` and `update`. you are not using the data in the update statement anyway so a `merge` is not really necessary.

Comment: Good questions and information I should have provided.  Yes, it is reproducible, it is a deadlock, and it single session.  Thanks Alex.

Comment: Haki, we originally had it in an insert/update, which is what led us to try the merge after it deadlocked.  I could try a fresh approach at it.  The application isn't multithreaded, so I have a hard time believing it is on the code side of thanks.  Thank Haki.

Comment: I fixed the layout, and also changed stored procedure to show an actual instance of its use.

Comment: I think @AlexPoole is correct, it sounds like a blocking issue.  What EXACTLY are you experiencing? Do you wait forever (blocking) or do you get an ORA error? (ora-00060)

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table you are merging into?

Comment: Yes, tbone I get teh 00060.  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Comment: Brian, a trigger exists that fires on every insert/update.  Used for added date, modified date.

Comment: It looks like a bug, but the only ones I can see for merge/deadlock with a single session are when parallelised, and are intermittent anyway. Not sure you're going to get far without the trace files unfortunately, and your DBA probably needs to raise an SR with Oracle.

Comment: oh, I see you're calling this from odp.net app.  My guess is that you're using connection pooling, and multiple sessions are executing this same update, some of same rows affected.  Almost all deadlock issues are design/app related, they cannot be completely avoided in db code, they show a design or approach issue.

Comment: Can you temporarily disable the trigger and retry the MERGE?  If so, does the deadlock still occur?